# Template Strings in Angular: How to bind a function?

Tags: angular, leaflet, template-strings

I wonder if it is possible to bind a function to a html Template via the template-string notation.

So if i do this

```
 let dynTamp = `<div> ${device.name} </div>`;
```

it works perfectly well, but this

```
let dynTamp = `<button (click)="${someFunction}"></button>`;
```

does not bind the function to the click event. Am I missing something here?

The Background: I am working with LeafletJs and dynamically create markers on a map, whose popovers should contain buttons:

```
this.devices.forEach(device => {

        L.marker([Number(device.map_x), Number(device.map_y)], {icon: this.icon})
          .bindPopup(`<h2> ${device.name}</h2>
                  <button (click)="${doThis}"></button>
                  <button (click)="${doThat}"></button>`)
          .addTo(this.map)           
    }
```

Comment: Yes. An angular expression is not a template string. It's an Angular expression. The syntax to call someFunction() when a button is clicked is `(click)="someFunction()"`. And Angular templates need to be compiled. You can't just dynamically generate HTML containing Angular markup and hope it works. It won't.

Comment: Well sure, we know that from AngularJS. In my first example though it does get compiled, that why I wondererd if there was a way to so so with functions also

Answer (score 2):

This should be the correct syntax :

```
let dynTamp = `<button (click)="someFunction()"></button>`;
```

I share an example of how to use a template string : [View Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chkmdg)

Comment: If I do so, the function does not get called on click

Comment: in which life cycle are you declaring "dynMap" ??

Comment: A I see, thank you! The difference is, that you use the String as a regular Angular Template, whereas I create the Template dynamically and add it to the Dom - after it`s compiled. That is why this works for you, but unfortunately not in my case.

Answer (score 0):

please replace with this

```
let dynTamp = `<button (click)="someFunction()"></button>`;
```

instead of

```
let dynTamp = `<button (click)="${someFunction}"></button>`;
```

An angular expression is not a template string. It's an Angular expression. The syntax to call someFunction() when a button is clicked is `(click)="someFunction()`".